# Firebase cloud function Deadline exceeded error in nested promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I have a firebase cloud function that is unable to finish executing. I suspect my code can be dramatically improved but I'm not quite sure how.

I've made the query as specific as possible to try and reduce the number of documents required to iterate through but that didn't solve the issue.

I get a Deadline Exceeded error which I suspect is due to the fact that I'm iterating through so many documents and trying to update them.

I increased the timeout (9 minutes)and memory allocation (2GB) in Google cloud console but that didn't help either.

```
exports.updatePollWinner = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).firestore.document('triggerAccuracyCalculation/{id}').onCreate(trigger => {
  const week = trigger.get('week');
  const scoringTags = ["STD", "0.25PPR", "0.5PPR", "PPR", "0.10PPC", "0.25PPC", "0.5PPC", "4PTPASS", "5PTPASS", "6PTPASS", "-2INT", "TEPREMIUM"]
  let winningChoiceIds = [];
  let totalPollIds = [];
  return db.collection("polls").where("sport", "==", 1).where("week", "==", week).where("pollType", "==", "WDIS").get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
      console.log("A");
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          totalPollIds.push(doc.id);
          let pollData = doc.data();
          // extract relevant scoring tags
          let tags = pollData.tags.filter(tag => scoringTags.includes(tag.code)).map(tag => tag.code);
          // if no scoring setting is tagged, then use STD - determine what STD is

          // extract player from each option
          let winner = {score: 0, choice: {}, choiceId: null};
          let cnt = 0;
          pollData.choices.forEach((choice) => {
            let choiceId = choice.id
            let mappedChoices = choice.players.map(player => {
              return { displayName: player.displayName, playerId: player.playerId, position: player.position, team: player.team }
            });

            // ToDo: What happens if someone posts a poll with two players in one option? This poll should be ignoree from accuracy calculation
            // ignmore if option has more than one player
            // if (mappedChoices.length > 1) return;

            const player = mappedChoices[0]

            // We can't score defense
            if (player.position === "DEF") {
              return;
            }
            const playerId = player.playerId;
            // Make FFN API call to retrieve stats for that player in that weekconst statsEndpoint = `https://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/player/json/${functions.config().ffnerd.key}${req.url}`;

            const statsEndpoint = `https://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/player/json/${functions.config().ffnerd.key}/${playerId}`;
            const json = {"Stats": {"2019": ""}, "Player": {}};
            https.get(statsEndpoint, (resp) => {
              let data = '';

              resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
              });

              resp.on('end', () => {
                const weekString = week.toString();
                const fetchedStats = JSON.parse(data).Stats
                if (!fetchedStats) return;
                const response = fetchedStats["2019"]
                if (!response) return;
                // TODO SCORE KICKERS AND DEFENSES
                const stats = response[weekString];
                let score = 0;


                stats["recYards"] ? score += parseInt(stats["recYards"]) / 10 : false
                stats["recTD"] ? score += parseInt(stats["recTD"]) * 6 : false
                stats["rushYards"] ? score += parseInt(stats["rushYards"]) / 10 : false
                stats["rushTD"] ? score += parseInt(stats["rushTD"]) * 6 : false
                stats["xpMade"] ? score += parseInt(stats["xpMade"]) : false
                stats["fgMade"] ? score += parseInt(stats["fgMade"]) * 3 : false
                stats["kickoffRet"] ? score += parseInt(stats["kickoffRet"]) / 10 : false
                stats["SackYards"] ? score -= parseInt(stats["SackYards"]) / 10 : false
                stats["fumbleLost"] ? score -= parseInt(stats["fumbleLost"]) * 2 : false

                // Determine winner
                // ToDo: handle ties
                if (score > winner.score) {
                  winner.score = score;
                  winner.choiceId = choiceId;
                  winner.choice = choice;
                }
                if (cnt>=pollData.choices.length-1){
                  // Save player object on the poll Document (include choice ID)
                  winningChoiceIds.push(winner.choiceId);
                  const pollDoc = db.doc(`polls/${doc.id}`);
                  pollDoc.update({winner: winner});
                }
                cnt++;
              });
            }).on("error", (err) => {
              console.log("Error: ", err.message);
            });

          });
      });
      console.log("B");
      return false;
  }).then(() => {
    console.log("C");
    let dateToQueryAfter = new Date(new Date("08/22/19").setHours(0,0,0,0))
    return db.collection("users").where("recentVote", ">", dateToQueryAfter).get()
  })
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    console.log("D");
    const promises = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const p = db.collection("votes").where("uid", "==", doc.id).where("week", "==", week).where("pollType", "==", "WDIS").get()
      promises.push(p)
    });
    return Promise.all(promises)
  })
  .then((querySnapshots) => {
    console.log("E");
    querySnapshots.forEach((querySnapshot) => {
      if (querySnapshot.docs.length <= 0) return;
      const uid = querySnapshot.docs[0].data().uid
      const retrieveUserDoc = db.doc(`users/${uid}`);
      let correctVotes = 0;
      let cnt = 0;
      let totalVotes = 0;
      let pollVoteIds = [];
      let pollVoteIdsCorrect = [];
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        const voteData = doc.data();
        if (totalPollIds.includes(voteData.poll)) {
          pollVoteIds.push(voteData.poll)
          totalVotes++;
          if (winningChoiceIds.includes(voteData.choice)) {
            pollVoteIdsCorrect.push(voteData.poll)
            correctVotes++;
          }
        }
        if (cnt>=querySnapshot.size-1){
          console.log("Updating user ID: ", uid);
          retrieveUserDoc.update({
            ['accuracyWeeks.week'+week]: true,
            ['accuracy.week'+week]: {
              totalVotes: totalVotes,
              correct: correctVotes,
              accuracy: correctVotes/totalVotes,
              correctVoteIds: pollVoteIdsCorrect,
              totalVoteIds: pollVoteIds
            }
          });
        }
        cnt++;
      })
    });
    console.log("F");
    return false;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
  });
});
```

Comment: You're ignoring the promises returned by each call to update().  I don't know if that's causing the error, but it will cause the function to behave poorly since you're allowing it to return before all the async work is complete.

Comment: which update are you referring to? sorry, i just want to clarify

Comment: All of them. Everything that returns a promise needs to be accounted for.

Comment: in both instances where I add a return statement in front of the update statement I get hit with the error "arrow function expected no return value" - Would you be kind enough to show me what you mean with a code example?